# JavaScript. Creating a dynamic table based on a user input

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to ask the user through a prompt for a number that is an: integer, greater than 0, and is numeric. I did that with a do while loop and seems to be working correctly. With that number I have to pass it to the function called "genTable" and create a table with a dynamic amount of rows based on what the user typed. However, with my current code I can't seem to get the table to appear on the page. Any ideas on where I went wrong and how to fix it?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>
<title>jsLoopDemo</title>

<!-- 
Honor Code: I acknowledge that this code represents my own work: CC
Date:  July 6, 2017
-->

<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="description" content="Create a chart with rows based on a number 
user chose." />
<meta name="keywords" content="loop, row, dynamic" />
<meta name="author" content="" />


<script type="text/javascript">


    do{
       var numChose = prompt("Please enter an interger greater than zero.");
    }while (isNaN(numChose) || numChose % 1 !== 0 || numChose < 1 );

    function genTable(numChose)
    {
        var table = document.createElement("TABLE");
        var tableBody = document.createElement("TBODY");
        table.appendChild(tableBody);
        var myTableDiv = document.getElementById("mytable");


        for (var r = 0; r <= numChose; r++)
            {
                var tr = document.createElement("TR");
                tableBody.appendChild(tr);
                var td = document.createElement("TD");
                tr.appendChild(td);
                td.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Row " + r));
            }
     myTableDiv.appendChild(table);
    }



</script>



</head>

<body> 

<div id="mytable">   
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

You need to actually call the function after the prompt, so you need to add a line after your do while:

```
genTable(numChose);
```

That still won't work, since the DOM will not be ready (`myTableDiv` will be undefined), so you need to wrap your entire code in an event listener:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    //do work
});
```

Comment: This worked wonderfully, However, I would appreciate some reasoning on why i need to do genTable(numChose); if its in the next line in the function. What is the difference?

Comment: writing `function genTable(numChose)` only _defines_ a function called `genTable` with a parameter `numChose`, but doesn't call it, you still need to do that. A function is usually used to reuse code, since it can be called repeatedly. If this is something that only happens once in your code, you can also scrap the function (just use the code that's in the function), and it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `<script>` code after the

```
<div id="mytable">   
</div>
```

in `<body>` so that the element is rendered on DOM while table is being generated and call the function

```
genTable(numChose);
```

after you get the number from user.