# Trying to create a dynamic table with vanilla Javascript, code not working

Tags: javascript, forms, for-loop, dynamic-tables

***What I'm trying to build:***

I'm trying to build a Pixel Art Maker, which is essentially an empty grid of user-determined size, and the colour of each box in the grid changes when you click on it.

***Problem:***

I managed to figure out the colour change, but can't get the table to appear at all.

I've already looked at [creating-a-dynamic-table-based-on-a-user-input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44980319/javascript-creating-a-dynamic-table-based-on-a-user-input)
which appears to be the closest thing I could find to what I'm attempting to achieve. There's a similar logic to the tables, but I'm too inexperienced to understand the differences between that code and mine.

***Codepen:***

[Codepen link](https://codepen.io/JayS5/project/editor/AaNBOq)

And here is my code snippet:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('#pixelCanvas')

const tbody = document.createElement('tbody');

canvas.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.target.style.background = 'black';
});

canvas.addEventListener('dblclick', function(e) {
  e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
});

// Store the value of columns
const column = document.getElementById('column').value;

// Store the value of rows
const row = document.getElementById('row').value;

// Access forms
const submitForm = document.querySelector('#submitForm');

submitForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // Prevents the submit button from refreshing the page by default
  debugger;
  for (r = 0; r < row; r++) {
    const tr = document.createElement('tr');
    tbody.appendChild(tr);
    for (c = 0; c < column; c++) {
      const td = document.createElement('td');
      tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    canvas.appendChild(tbody);
  }



});
```

```html
<h1>Pixel Art Maker</h1>

<fieldset>
  <legend>Grid Size</legend>

  <form id='submitForm'>

    <label for="height">Columns:</label>
    <input type="number" id="column" placeholder="Key in an integer" step="1" />

    <label for="width">Rows:</label>
    <input type="number" id="row" placeholder="Min: 1, max: 100" min="1" max="100" />

    <div>
      <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
  </form>
</fieldset>

<br>

<div>
  <table id="pixelCanvas">
    <!--  Dynamic pixel canvas  -->
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: the `const` variable(row and column) assignment should not have `.value` with them get their value inside the `submit`'s click function because you are setting a blank value to them at the beginning and as a result your loop in not working.

Comment: @vikscool Thank you so much! That was a very clear explanation and solved the issue. Do you know how to remove the old grid if you want to change it from 5x5 to 6x6 for example?

Comment: on your `submit` buttons click event call `document.getElementById('pixelCanvas').innerHTML='';` at the beginning.

Comment: @vikscool Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you have called the no of rows and columns at starting so its **NULL** at initial, get no of rows and column after click submit.
Checkout this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hdsbvtLw/2/

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('#pixelCanvas')

const tbody = document.createElement('tbody');

canvas.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  e.target.style.background = 'black';
});

canvas.addEventListener('dblclick', function(e){
  e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
});

// Store the value of columns


// Access forms
const submitForm = document.querySelector('#submitForm');

submitForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();  // Prevents the submit button from refreshing the page by default
  tbody.innerHTML='';
  const column = document.getElementById('column').value;

// Store the value of rows
const row = document.getElementById('row').value;
  console.log(row);
  for (r = 0; r < row; r++) {
    const tr = document.createElement('tr');
    tbody.appendChild(tr);
    for (c = 0; c < column; c++) {
      const td = document.createElement('td');
      tr.appendChild(td);
    } 
    canvas.appendChild(tbody);  
  }
  
  
  
});
```

```css
/**
 * index.scss
 * - Add any styles you want here!
 */
body {
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

table, thead, tbody, tfoot, tr, td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

td {
  width: 30px;
}

tr {
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  
  <!--  Meta  -->
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Pixel Art</title>
  
  <!--  Styles  -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/index.processed.css">
</head>
<body>
  
  <h1>Pixel Art Maker</h1>
  
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Grid Size</legend>
    
    <form id = 'submitForm'>
    
    <label for="height">Columns:</label>
    <input type="number" id="column" 
           placeholder="Key in an integer" step="1" />

    <label for="width">Rows:</label>
    <input type="number" id="row"
           placeholder="Min: 1, max: 100"
           min="1" max="100" />
      
        <div>
            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
      </div>
    </form>
  </fieldset>
  
  <br>
  
  <div>
    <table id="pixelCanvas">
      <!--  Dynamic pixel canvas  -->
    </table>
  </div>
  
  <!-- Scripts -->
  <script src="scripts/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That's solved the main problem, but now I've got a new one unfortunately. When I add a 5x5 grid for example, trying to change it to 6x6 doesn't remove the old grid. It adds another grid on top of the old 5x5 grid. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: It works!! Man, I spent days trying to figure this out. Thank you so much @Harish!